# Exception when deserialize file with Body class of kinect with C#

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, kinect, binaryfiles

I want save Body in a binary file so after use it.
I serialized in different files every Body vector (is it possible save in the same file?) but when i deserialized it i have this exception:

```
Eccezione non gestita di tipo 'System.NullReferenceException' in ConsoleApplication6.exe
Ulteriori informazioni: Riferimento a un oggetto non impostato su un'istanza di oggetto.
```

With debug i have this exception details:

```
{"Fine del flusso raggiunta prima del termine dell'analisi."}   System.Exception {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException}
```

This is my code:

```
public static void serialize(Body[] bodySerialized,String path)
        {
            Stream stream=null;
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
                bFormatter.Serialize(stream, bodySerialized);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                    stream.Close();

            }
        }
public static Body[] deserialize(String path)
        {
            Body[] bodyDeserialized = null;
            Stream stream = null;

            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
                bodyDeserialized = (Body[])bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.ToString();
            }
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(bodyDeserialized.Length);
            return bodyDeserialized;
        }
```

where is the error? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Body in SDK 2.0 is not serializable. I have used a wrapper serializable class and now goes correctly

Comment: can you link the serializable class that you used?